# Config FirePHP on laravel

Tags: laravel, firephp

I'm trying to config FirePhp on my Laravel project, 
I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/plus3interactive/laravel4-firephp) ,
But on the part were i should update the providers list in the console -

```
$ php artisan config:publish p3in/firephp
```

i get an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Config\Repository::package()
```

Here is how my providers array looks like:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    'P3in\Firephp\FirephpServiceProvider',



    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Darryldecode\Cart\CartServiceProvider::class,



],
```

Comment: You need to replace `'P3in\Firephp\FirephpServiceProvider'`, by `P3in\Firephp\FirephpServiceProvider::class` in the poviders array.

Comment: Thanks, it was my first attempt, but unfortunately i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function was removed, you can [view the commit here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/64c15a35d9578748671639748b83b21d16dbd6c2).

You can downgrade your version of Laravel to support this package, or find a package that has been maintained in the last 2 years.